# CSS: Formatting a specific style

Tags: css

In pyroCMS it echo's its navigation like:

```
<li class="last current">
    <a href="http://develop.jzm.co.nz/pyrocms/portfolio">portfolio</a>
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is format the `li.current` and in my css code I have the following:

```
header nav li.current{
    font:18px Myriad Pro;
    color:#2d2d2d;
}
```

But this does not seem to be sticking to the current page,  Are there any other ways that I could code the css for the particular css current class?

Comment: That should just target any list items with the class of current, I can't see anything wrong with it. There must be a current class on more than one list item or you're missing a closing </li>. If not, that's very strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have other rules that apply to anchors? Try

```
header nav li.current > a
```